# LESS support in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: less, visual-studio-express

I am wondering if there is any way to get support for LESS in the 2010 express edition of visual studio. I know there is a plugin available, but you cannot install that on a express edition. Installing the 2012 edition (which has less support built in) is not an option.

Edit:
To clarify, at the very least I am looking for color coding.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to configure the css or js editor for the extension in the tools, options window of visual studio. But other than that (and even that is only half a solution), VS Express doesn't support extensibility, so the official answer is unfortunately: no.

To enable these types of features you'll need at least VS Pro.

Comment: I was afraid of that :( I couldnt find any way to get the css editor functions to work for less either. Guess ill just have to use a seperate editor for the less files (still better then the alternative which is editing in plain text mode).

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use WebMatrix.  It has the same LESS editor as Visual Studio, and it's free:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

If you want auto-compilation/minification, there's an extension for that:
http://extensions.webmatrix.com/packages/OrangeBits